# Plotting time series with seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 2 lists. One represents time and looks like

```
time=[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 0, 5, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 0, 1, 53),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 0, 1, 56),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 0, 1, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 0, 1, 40),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 7, 0, 1, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 7, 0, 1, 30),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 0, 1, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 0, 1, 20)]
```

and the other represents corresponding data points:

```
data=[51.024,3.2179,105.18,31.176,1.1123,1.7861,109.65,0.0,123.890,523.897]
```

plotting this with matplotlib is easy, but the rest of the statistics is done with seaborn and I would like to keep the visuals and use seaborn for the whole set of results. When I use `seaborn.tsplot` I get the following error `index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape seaborn`. The data list does contain duplicates, but they are at different time points and cannot be removed. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: if I create pandas dataframe, I can plot the y value using `sns.tsplot(y)`, but I want to be able to use my values for x-axis, not the generated values.

Comment: You might want to see my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914502/getting-word-recommendations-based-on-a-given-word-from-a-list-of-words#comment46087200_28914502) on providing sample data

Comment: I added one part of actual data. time is already sorted.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you provide a small, complete example of the problem -- data and the failing line of code that we can cut-and-paste in one action into our environments to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to plotting your data with seaborn, you can use `matplotlib`'s styles feature to get the same look while still plotting within `matplotlib`:

```
from matplotlib import style
# Seaborn's visual styling was inspired by ggplot,
#   so this style should be very similar:
style.use('ggplot')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
time=[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 0, 5, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 0, 1, 53),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 0, 1, 56),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 0, 1, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 0, 1, 40),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 7, 0, 1, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 7, 0, 1, 30),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 0, 1, 2),datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 0, 1, 20)]
data=[51.024,3.2179,105.18,31.176,1.1123,1.7861,109.65,0.0,123.890,523.897]

# Replace this with whatever code you were using to plot
#   within matplotib, the styling should still be applied
plt.plot(time, data, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can also just plot with matplotlib functions when seaborn is imported and it will pick up the seaborn style.