# how to speed up nested loops in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, nested-loops

I am trying to write a piece of nested loops in my algorithm, and meet some problems that the whole algorithm takes too long time due to these nested loops. I am quite new to Python (as you may find from my below unprofessional code :( ) and hopefully someone can guide me a way to speed up my code!

The whole algorithm is for fire detection in multi 1500*6400 arrays. A small contextual analyse is applied when go through the whole array. The contextual analyse is performed in a dynamically assigned windows size way. The windows size can go from 11*11 to 31*31 until the validate values inside the sampling windows are enough for the next round calculation, for example like below:

```
def ContextualWindows (arrb4,arrb5,pfire):
####arrb4,arrb5,pfire are 31*31 sampling windows from large 1500*6400 numpy array
    i=5
    while i in range (5,16):
        arrb4back=arrb4[15-i:16+i,15-i:16+i]
        ## only output the array data when it is 'large' enough 
        ## to have enough good quality data to do calculation       
        if np.ma.count(arrb4back)>=min(10,0.25*i*i):
            arrb5back=arrb5[15-i:16+i,15-i:16+i]
            pfireback=pfire[15-i:16+i,15-i:16+i]
            canfire=0
            i=20
        else: 
            i=i+1

###unknown pixel: background condition could not be characterized
    if i!=20: 
        canfire=1
        arrb5back=arrb5
        pfireback=pfire
        arrb4back=arrb4
    return (arrb4back,arrb5back,pfireback,canfire)
```

Then this dynamic windows will be feed into next round test, for example:

```
b4backave=np.mean(arrb4Windows)
b4backdev=np.std(arrb4Windows)
if b4>b4backave+3.5*b4backdev:
    firetest=True
```

To run the whole code to my multi 1500*6400 numpy arrays, it took over half an hour, or even longer. Just wondering if anyone got an idea how to deal with it? A general idea which part I should put my effort to would be greatly helpful!

Many thanks!

Comment: Might be better for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: not a change to the complexity but I would use `while 5 <= i < 16`

Comment: You could also change it to a for loop and a break, with else clause i = 20 and then reverse the test... There are no nested loops, just lots of slicing, numpy is supposed to create views, so shouldn't be that slow.

Comment: Very hard to answer the question in the current state. Can you add sample input for the function and any imports to your code? Make it so we can copy, paste and run your code without needing to guess the format of your data. Try pasting it into a file yourself and if it does not run then edit it until it does and the update the code in the question to match. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19268937/553404) for a data-as-code example, [these R guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/553404) and [this SO help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `codereview` doesn't get enough traffic.  `numpy` speedup questions like this are quite common here on `SO`.

Comment: I'd focus on speeding up the inside of the `while` loop.  Iterating 10 times isn't much of a problem if the if each iteration step is fast.  But if this is a sliding window problem, there is a `strided` method that may be able to 'vectorize' it.

Comment: @hpaulj that was true 3 years ago. 45K visitors/day is quite a bit of traffic in StackLand.

Comment: But `numpy` traffic is still weak, 134 questions tagged v 16,000 here.  Same for followers.

Comment: A plus for moving this to `codereview` is that the standards for the question are tighter.  A non-runnable excerpt like this would not be tolerated.

Comment: SO is in its own league. You can't compare a site that has dozens of millions of users against any other. But a lot of answerers on Code Review don't care what the language is.. especially in the [performance] tag. You have a point about the *example code* though, but if everyone thought "I'll post on SO, CR is too small", then CR wouldn't have graduated like it did. CR doubled in size over the past 18 months... and I bet there would be more votes on CR if the question was on-topic and answered there.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `while` loops if speed is a concern. The loop lends itself to a `for` loop as start and end are fixed. Additionally, your code does a lot of copying which isn't really necessary. The rewritten function:

```
def ContextualWindows (arrb4,arrb5,pfire):
    ''' arrb4,arrb5,pfire are 31*31 sampling windows from 
        large 1500*6400 numpy array '''

    for i in range (5, 16):
        lo = 15 - i  # 10..0
        hi = 16 + i  # 21..31
        #  only output the array data when it is 'large' enough
        #  to have enough good quality data to do calculation
        if np.ma.count(arrb4[lo:hi, lo:hi]) >= min(10, 0.25*i*i):
            return (arrb4[lo:hi, lo:hi], arrb5[lo:hi, lo:hi], pfire[lo:hi, lo:hi], 0)
    else:    #  unknown pixel: background condition could not be characterized
        return (arrb4, arrb5, pfire, 1)
```

For clarity I've used style guidelines from PEP 8 (like extended comments, number of comment chars, spaces around operators etc.). Copying of a windowed `arrb4` occurs twice here but only if the condition is fulfilled and this will happen only once per function call. The `else` clause will be executed only if the `for`-loop has run to it's end. We don't even need a `break` from the loop as we exit the function altogether.
Let us know if that speeds up the code a bit. I don't think it'll be much but then again there isn't much code anyway.

Comment: The end points aren't fixed.  He starts at 5, but can quit before 16.  A for-loop with a break should work, but I don't think it will make much difference in speed.

Comment: My suggestion contains a `break` as well in the `if...then` statement, only that it returns from the function altogether. It wouldn't work without as the OP wants to quit prematurely when the conditions is met. So the loop may run to it's end or may quit before that, just as in the original code. In my opinion the flow lends itself to a `for` loop with a `break` more than to a `while` loop. Avoiding to copy parts of the arrays will probably have more effect than this, granted.

Comment: In my tests, 1 iteration takes 50us, all 10 500us.  Breaking early if possible is a good thing.  For with break is clearer syntax, but not much different in speed.

Answer (score 0):

I've run some time tests with `ContextualWindows` and variants.  One `i` step takes about 50us, all ten about 500.

This simple iteration takes about the same time:

```
[np.ma.count(arrb4[15-i:16+i,15-i:16+i]) for i in range(5,16)]
```

The iteration mechanism, and the 'copying' arrays are minor parts of the time.  Where possible `numpy` is making views, not copies.

I'd focus on either minimizing the number of these `count` steps, or speeding up the `count`.

---

Comparing times for various operations on these windows:

First time for 1 step:

```
In [167]: timeit [np.ma.count(arrb4[15-i:16+i,15-i:16+i]) for i in range(5,6)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.9 us per loop
```

now for the 10 steps:

```
In [139]: timeit [arrb4[15-i:16+i,15-i:16+i].shape for i in range(5,16)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.7 us per loop

In [140]: timeit [np.sum(arrb4[15-i:16+i,15-i:16+i]>500) for i in range(5,16)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 390 us per loop

In [141]: timeit [np.ma.count(arrb4[15-i:16+i,15-i:16+i]) for i in range(5,16)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 464 us per loop
```

Simply indexing does not take much time, but testing for conditions takes substantially more.

`cumsum` is sometimes used to speed up sums over sliding windows.  Instead of taking sum (or mean) over each window, you calculate the `cumsum` and then use the differences between the front and end of window.

Trying something like that, but in 2d - cumsum in both dimensions, followed by differences between diagonally opposite corners:

```
In [164]: %%timeit
   .....: cA4=np.cumsum(np.cumsum(arrb4,0),1)
   .....: [cA4[15-i,15-i]-cA4[15+i,15+i] for i in range(5,16)]
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.1 us per loop
```

This is almost 10x faster than the (nearly) equivalent `sum`.  Values don't quite match, but timing suggest that this may be worth refining.